# Run cmdlets on trusted domains

Tags: windows, powershell, command, powershell-cmdlet, trusted

As the title above. I'm curious that is it possible to run whether cmdlets or command lines on the trusted domains?

As far as I know that we can retrieve resources between those trusted domains, in term of running cmdlets on it is still my suspicious questions.

Because I want to install AD-module on trusted domain via a trusting domain. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes. There is not restriction in running. What actually you want to achieve ? this question is very much vague. if you are using the latest server, then by default the ad module will be loaded. What do you mean by install AD-module ? you just need to import it unless you are using in non-dc machines

Comment: @RanadipDutta Hi, tks for replying, what I want is to install the "AD-Module" to the trusted domain from a trusting domain. An instance, I have a domain A, and B, both are trusted transitively. I want to install the  "Ad-module" on domain B from domain A without logging in to it. I'm currently using windows server 2008 or less.

Comment: straight forward ans is Yes you can do that. Enjoy :)

Comment: @RanadipDutta it would be really nice if you can tell me how to do this?. IMO,because we can't be sure that the trusted domain is living in the same forest which means whether you install on the DC ( root domain) , very likely it won't install on another forest which contains trusted domain that you need.

Comment: Point is if you have the credentials for different domain (if diff), if the PSReporting is enabled, then you are good to go. You can use invoke-command and you can import the module (if logging in DC) else you can use unc path also to access the psm1 and get it imported.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thank you so much!. I will look for it :). Why I didn't think about using invoke-command omw!